# Unstructed data field: Query all values from array of objects by key

Tags: postgresql, query, json, array, postgresql-11

I have a table that has a unique ID, and a second 'collumn' named 'data' that contains simple key/value items like:

```
"nickname": "value"
"fullName":  "value"
"office": "value"
"unity":  "value"
```

and a few, more elaborated structure items like:

```
"address":
    {
        "city": "value",
        "state": "value",
    },
```

and

```
"personalVehicle":
    [
        {
            "brand": "value",
            "model": "value",
            "plate": "value",
            "color": "value"             
        },
        {
            "brand": "value",
            "model": "value",
            "plate": "value",
            "color": "value"             
        }               
    ]
```

Where, as you can see, `personalVehicle` is a key that stores an array of objects, in which every object has it's own simple key/value items.

I can query specific key values from `address` for all registries: `SELECT data->'address'->'city' as city FROM person`

```
+------------+
|    city    |
|------------|
| "city1"    |
| "city2"    |
| "city3"    |
+------------+
```

Here is the situation: I can query all info about the vehicles with `SELECT data->'personalVehicle' as vehicles FROM person`

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| vehicles                                                                                                                                                         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| [ { "brand": "Toyota", "model": "Corolla", "plate": "AAA-1111", "color": "Red" }, { "brand": "Ford", "model": "Focus", "plate": "ZZZ-9999", "color": "Blue" } ]  |
| <null>                                                                                                                                                           |
| [ { "brand": "Hyundai", "model": "Tucson", "plate": "ABC-1212", "color": "Grey" } ]                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I cannot retrieve an specific key for all objects, when the objects are inside of an array; in which case, I need to specify the index: `SELECT data->personalVehicle->0->model as model from person`

```
+-------------+
|   model     |
|-------------|
| "Toyota"    |
| <null>      |
| "Hyundai"   |
+-------------+
```

This guy up here, is the first index of the array, that is, the first car. I need to get the models for all N number of cars that the person might have.

How do I do that? Query that without specifying the index?

Comment: I came to a workaround using a subquery but it's far from what I wanted: `SELECT id,vehicle->>'brand' as brand FROM (SELECT id,json_array_elements(data->'personalVehicle') as vehicle from person) as brand` but that returns me one row at a time; that is, if the person has 3 cars, it will return 3 rows with the same id for that person. 1 - Chevrolet, 1 - Ford, 1 - Hyundai. I'm sure there is a way to get a array for example, containing all brands, making it one row per person: `1  - {Chevrolet, Ford, Hyundai}`

Answer (score 0):

Grab the elements from the json array with `json_array_elements` and reassemble them with `json_agg`:

```sql
select id, json_agg(cars) from (
  select 
    id,
    json_array_elements(data->'personalVehicle')->>'model' as cars
  from t
) subq
group by id
```

Output:

```
1   ["Toyota", "Honda"]
3   ["Chevrolet", "Ford"]
2   ["Renault", "Citroën"]
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e96869/30).